# JS code not working on all data retrieved from Django Model

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm retrieving an `endDate` field from Django model using forloop on HTML page.
I want to check whether all the endDate coming are less that today's date or not. For that I'm using JS code.

My code is able to perform checking only on first date retrieved but it's not working on other dates.

Here's my **HTML code** for retrieving data:

```
{% for p in object_list %}
    <h4>{{ p.jobName }}</h4>
    <p><b style="color: red">Expires On: </b><b>{{ p.endDate }}</b></p>

    <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}" target="_blank">View info</a>    

    <input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="variable" value="{{ p.endDate }}">
    <span id="check"></span>            

{% endfor %}
```

**JavaScript code** to check date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
    var endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    var ToDate = new Date();
    if(new Date(endDate).getTime()<=ToDate.getTime()){
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "Expired";
        document.getElementById("check").className = "label danger";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "Active";
        document.getElementById("check").className = "label success";
    }
</script>
```

I have 2 `{{ p.jobName }}` right now. First one should show **Expired** while second should show **Active**.
My code is working only for first date i.e., for Computer Admin only.

Here's what I'm getting the output:
[image]

Can anybody tell me what's the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `span#check` being populated with the text "Active"?

Comment: @JaredASutton Yes. It's working for Active as well. The problem is it's workig for the first date only and not for others.

Comment: Your JS code will only ever work for a single element, that with ID `endDate`. Does your HTML contain multiple elements with that same ID? If so, that's invalid HTML, and is why your JS isn't working - `getElementById` returns a *single* element. If you want this to work on multiple, use a class instead, and something like `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: In fact, I've just noticed you've shared your Django template code too, so I can confirm this is *exactly* the problem. I'll type up in an answer how to fix it.

Comment: Although as an aside, I can't see from this code why you can't just do this date processing on the server side in Python, and include the appropriate logic in the template, rather than doing it in client-side JS.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Okay. I get it. I can just set a flag value as active or expired according to the present date on server-side and retrieve it directly in template. Thanks for this. Also, it would be great if you could share the answer for this. It would be good for learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what I've already said in the comments:

The essence of your problem is here:

```
{% for p in object_list %}
...   
    <input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="variable" value="{{ p.endDate }}">
    <span id="check"></span> 
...
{% endfor %}
```

An HTML document can only ever have *one* element of a particular ID (otherwise it doesn't "ID" the element very well - this is part of the HTML spec). In your case, whenever the loop has more than one element, you will end up with multiple elements, all with the `endDate` ID, as well as multiples with the `check` ID.

Repeating an ID like this, as well as being wrong in itself, can have a major functional impact - as you're seeing in your code. Namely that since there is only ever supposed to be (at most) one element of a given ID, any Javascript code that runs on the page is entitled to assume that this is the case. And in particular, [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns an object representing a *single* HTML element, as opposed to similar methods such as [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which return a "collection" of DOM nodes. (Because a class, unlike an ID, can be applied to multiple elements in the same document.)

So that, in a nutshell, is how to solve the problem you're having. Simply replace the `id="endDate"` in the above to `class="endDate"`, similarly with `check`, and alter your javascript to take this into account. Not only do you have to change the `getElementById` method to `getElementsByClassName`, you also have to take into account that this returns a collection (which you can loop over with `.forEach`), and that you need to target the neighbouring `.check` span rather than the first, or any old random one. The following code is one way to make it work (note the use of ES6 `Array.from` to convert the collection to a genuine Array so you can use `.forEach`):

```
var endDateElts = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("endDate"));
var ToDate = new Date();

endDateElts.forEach(function(dateElt) {
    var endDate = dateElt.value;
    var check = dateElt.nextSibling;
    if(new Date(endDate).getTime()<=ToDate.getTime()){
        check.innerHTML = "Expired";
        check.className = "label danger";
    }
    else{
        check.innerHTML = "Active";
        check.className = "label success";
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay I got the problem. Your code is running fine but `innerHTML` is not working in this case. I tried `console.log(check.innerHTML)` and it's giving correct result(for both dates) but it's not visible on HTML template.

Comment: That sounds strange. If it's logging correctly to the console then I assume it's a CSS issue for why you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on

```
{% for p in object_list %}
    <h4>{{ p.jobName }}</h4>
    <p><b style="color: red">Expires On: </b><b>{{ p.endDate }}</b></p>

    <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}" target="_blank">View info</a>    

    <input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="variable" value="{{ p.endDate }}">
    <span id="check"></span>            

{% endfor %}
```

I would assume that you have multiple objects with the same **ID** hence the reason why the JS is only working on the first `endDate` and `check` object.

```
<input type="hidden" id="endDate" name="variable" value="{{ p.endDate }}">
<span id="check"></span>
```

**What you should do:**

1. Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get multiple DOM elements
   with the same class name.
2. Iterate through the `NodeList` and perform the operations that you wish to perform.

```js
const endDates = document.querySelectorAll('.endDate');
const checks = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
let ToDate = new Date();
let i = 0;
for (const endDate of endDates){
    if(new Date(endDate.value).getTime()<=ToDate){
      checks[i].innerHTML = "Expired";
      checks[i].className = "label danger";
    }
    else{
      checks[i].innerHTML = "Active";
      checks[i].className = "label";
    }
    i++;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
<input type="text" class="endDate" name="variable" value="2019-11-29">
<span class="check"></span>
<br>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
<input type="text" class="endDate" name="variable" value="2019-11-24">
<span class="check"></span>
<br>
</div>
<div class="container-3">
<input type="text" class="endDate" name="variable" value="2019-11-27">
<span class="check"></span>
</div>
```

**Notes**
Not very sure why you would want to do the validation in the front-end if you can do it on your `views.py`. @Robin Zigmond gave a very good suggestion of just doing it on the backend and populate the template with the result.

Comment: Your code is working only if I provide statically different input tags. But in my case, dates are dynamic and so I won't be knowing it's count and so can't use several input tags.

Comment: Yes I can use it in back-end to work. It just didn't struck in my mind but thanks to @Robin ZIgmond.

Comment: Great, his suggestion is really the way to go. Happy coding!